# PHP cookie expire

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Okay, when logging in I simply set a cookie to `true` and set it to expire in a fortnight. but if the user wants to logout, how do I edit that cookie to say false or just make it go away by expiring it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setcookie() again. You can either set it's value to false or make it expire in the past. Both should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

From PHP:

```
setcookie('yourCookie', '');
```

You can also do it in JavaScript

```
document.cookie='yourCookie=';
```